# Selenium locate <img> nested in <div> class

Tags: html, testing, selenium, xpath

I have the following html code:

```
<span id="spanId" class="myThumbnails">
    <div class="Thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:12px;text-align:center;">
        <img id="thumbl00_cph_Img1" style="border-width:0px;" src="http://someImg.jpg"></img>
        <input id="thumbl00_cph_Img1" type="hidden" value="http://someImg.jpg"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="Thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:12px;text-align:center;"></div>
    <div class="Thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:12px;text-align:center;"></div>
    <div class="Thumbnail" style="margin-bottom:12px;text-align:center;"></div>

</span>
```

I've extracted the `span` using `xpath` & then `findElements` by `className` but now I need the inner `<img>` src attribute, since the id is generated i can't use it is there a way to extract img?

Answer (score 1):

WebElement has [getAttribute](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) method. That does exactly what you want. So your code could be something similar to:

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//div[@class=\"Thumbnail\"]/img").getAttribute("src")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery selector

```
$('span#spanId img').src
```

in case there is only 1 img tag, if there is more than 1 img tag, just use loop to get src attribute

Comment: -1, this is not a good idea. This can be done very easily using native methods in Selenium.